# How to re-download React web-app

Tags: reactjs, web-applications

I want to re-download the deployed React webapp bundle when a newer version is available.

I can alert the webapp that there is a new front-end bundle version available.

But I don't know how to redownload the latest webapp bundle from the cloud. (i.e. hard refresh)

How can I do this?

Comment: add a hash key to your file name that changes when a new version is deployed

Comment: Share with us your environment (webpack , are u using git,.. so on ? ) and we will give you a pretty solution.

Comment: I'm using the default create-react-app setup with webpack.

Answer (score 0):

The webpack setup that ships with create-react-app **automatically adds a hash to the filename of the build artifact** during the production build process.

If your code changes, the build will produce a new hash, forcing cache invalidation.

---

More on this in the [create-react-app docs](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app#npm-run-build-or-yarn-build).